# Execute Python files from a main file and stop running when an assertion fails in any of the files

Tags: python, import, assert, try-except

I want to run several Python files from a main file.
I am doing it using the following custom function in `my_module`:

```
import os

def run(file):
    os.system(f"python3 -m folder.subfolder.{file}")
```

In the main file I have:

```
from folder.my_module import run

run("first_file")
run("second_file")
```

Inside `first_file` and `second_file` I have written several assertions. 
**The `second_file` must not run unless all the assertions have run without raising an error in the `first_file`.**

In general, **I would like the whole program to stop running when an error occurs in any of the files.**

I have tried:

```
assert run("first_file"), "Error in file 1"
assert run("second_file"), "Error in file 2"
```

But the program stops working always after the first file has run, regardless of an exception occurring or not.

I have also tried:

```
try:
    run("first_file")
except:
    raise

try:
    run("second_file")
except:
    raise
```

But this does not have any effect: The `second_file` runs even if there was an assertion failing in `first_file`.

Comment: What is `run`??

Comment: Well you're not returning any output from `first_file` and `second_file`, so even if they each raise AssertionError you won't know - consider catching its output.

Comment: Have a look at the `subprocess` module. `os.system` gives you no control over the process.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion will always fail here because `run` returns `None`, which in turn evaluates to `False`.

A simple fix:

```py
def run(file):
    os.system(f"python3 -m folder.subfolder.{file}")
    return True
```

*EDIT*

I had to double check the `os` module. `os.system` will return the exit code of the program you're running so you should actually be comparing that to `0` (normal non error exit status) like so:

```py
def run(file):
    return 0 == os.system(f"python3 -m folder.subfolder.{file}")
```

Comment: sys.exit also works. Would want to know whats wrong with that ?

Comment: @RajVerma i understand that but this goes against the OPs current implementation (ie the use of `os.system("python3 ...")`) Tbh: I would personally do something completely different if given the same task which would use neither `sys` or `os`.

Comment: hmm ok. I thought it can be handled by exiting if there is an exception.

Comment: @RajVerma that's true too but the big difference is that when doing `os.system(python...`, the module will also evaluate any code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` whereas it won't be touched if you only `import` the module, the module must be treated as the applications "entrypoint" to get through the `main()`.

Comment: @smassey, that is working. Thank you for the fix! 
I am aware it may not be the most elegant approach, but it works.

Comment: "it may not be the most elegant approach, but it works" :) Story of my life :D

Answer (score 0):

The `os.system(f"python3 -m folder.subfolder.{file}")` command will return the exit code of the supplied command. It just so happens that a Python program that ends with an AssertionError will have an exit code of 2 (on linux, may be different elsewhere), although really any non-zero code means error.

You can test this yourself on the command line:

```
$ python3 -c "assert True"
$ echo $?
0
$ python3 -c "assert False"
$ echo $?
2
```

Simply check the return value of your `os.system()` call.